# Move rows based on "yes" to new book/sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have found a ton of these scripts. But not what I need.  I am looking for a script that I can link to a trigger. When triggered every row with a  "yes" in column 8 (H) Will be moved to another sheet With its on separate Google Sheets ID. (Sheet 1). My script works. BUT it takes everything to the new sheet. And I only need the ones that have "yes" in column 8 (H). I have found scripts that do it on edit to the same book. But not on trigger to another Google Sheets ID.

```
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Source ID').getSheetByName('Admin'),
        sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange(4, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(),
        targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Destination ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);
    sourceSheet.getRange(6, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a way to filter `sourceValues`. For this, you could add loop or to use `filterByText(Object[][] data, int columnIndex, String value)` from [2D arrays library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library) or another similar library.

Perhaps the easiest solution is to use FILTER or QUERY built-in functions to filter data prior to get it by the script.